# How to SELECT an specific value or any other in a 1-N tables relation

Tags: mysql, select, mariadb

I would like to find a query to perform the following results, I've tried a lot of differents methods but I can't really find the proper way to do it, I would appreciate if someone can help me on this.

Keep in mind that I can have a lot of different languages and I always want to prioritize one.

Having the following tables:

item

| id | info |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Etc |
| 2 | Etc |

item_translation

| item_id | lang_id | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | English Translation for item 1 |
| 1 | 2 | French translation for item 1 |
| 2 | 2 | French translation for item 2 |

I would like to select all items and only one item_translation for each item prioritizing a language.
For example if I would like to select all items prioritizing language 1 it should return the following:

| id | info | value | lang_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Etc | English Translation for item 1 | 1 |
| 2 | Etc | French translation for item 2 | 2 |

And if I would like to prioritize language 2:

| id | info | value | lang_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Etc | French translation for item 1 | 2 |
| 2 | Etc | French translation for item 2 | 2 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prioritize `lang_id` #1 you can do:

```
select
  i.id,
  i.info,
  x.value,
  x.lang_id
from item i
left join (
  select *,
    row_number() over(partition by item_id 
                      order by case when lang_id = 
      1 -- lang_id to prioritize
      then 1 else 2 end) as rn
  from item_translation
) x on x.item_id = i.id and x.rn = 1
```

Result:

```
 id  info  value                           lang_id 
 --- ----- ------------------------------- ------- 
 1   Etc   English Translation for item 1  1       
 2   Etc   French Translation for item 2   2
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xvyUTxiJZ3oQrGJiZo7WKa/0).

It will show:

- When multiple languages are available it will prioritize the preferred language.
- When the preferred language is not available it will select a *random* other.
- When no translation is available it will show nulls.

Comment: Just tried your query, it returns null for values of the columns that don't have the prioritized language.

Comment: The result of a copypaste of your query: [Image](https://ibb.co/61SzjHz)

Comment: The problem in your query is that the subselect is making the select over all the table and it is not filtering with the item_id, the item_id value is given in the join parameters so it is ignored in the subselect, as the i.id is in a outer query, it can't be passed to the subquery, I hope I explained myself.

Comment: @FrancescArolas I think the query returns the correct result (I may be wrong). If that's the case, the problem you are concerned about is about "performance" of the query due to the late filtering. The ideal solution is to use lateral queries, a feature that MariaDB and MySQL don't yet have (unlike PostgreSQL, DB2, Oracle, SQL Server).

Comment: The query returns the wrong result as it is returning null when it has values.

Comment: @FrancescArolas I had forgotten to add the `PARTITION BY` section. See the updated solution.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, it works like a charm, thank you.